# What does "surface area" refer to in the formula for thermal radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics

For an object with temperature $T_1$ in an environment with uniform temperature $T_2$, the formula for rate of heat transfer by radiation is
$$P=\sigma eA(T_2^4-T_1^4)$$
where A is referred to as the surface area of the object.

However, for instance, if I have a cube lying on the ground, will the bottom face of the cube contribute to this surface area? In other words, if the length of the cube is $l$, is $A=6l^2$ or $5l^2$?

I have this doubt because I am unsure whether the bottom face, being only in contact with the ground, can contribute to radiation from the object.

Comment: If you draw a surface $A$ in between the two objects, the power per unit area is $P$, and the power exchanged through that given surface is $PA$. It has little to do with the objects emitting the radiation.

Comment: radiation doesnt matter with surface being in contact , it will lose heat via conduction too but radiation takes place regularly as usual for the object